# Using babel-polyfill with webpack

Tags: reactjs, token, loader, jsx, babel-polyfill

I keep on encountering the following **error** when trying to use the babel-polyfill with webpack. How should i use it without the loader like babel-loader? It was mentioned that it will emulate the `es2015` environment.

```
ERROR in ./components/App.component.jsx
Module parse failed: /home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/components/App.component.jsx Unexpected token (6:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:1)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1861:32)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1796:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseFunctionBody (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2098:24)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseArrowExpression (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2087:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseParenArrowList (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1902:17)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1870:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1796:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseVar (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1034:28)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseVarStatement (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:917:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:706:19)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/home/krishna/AndroidStudioProjects/jancan/web/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
 @ multi main
```

Edit

my webpack config

```
module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './components/App.component.jsx'],
    output: {
        path: 'dist/',
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      loader: 'babel', // 'babel-loader' is also a valid name to reference
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015','react']
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

I have added babel-loader and still i am getting same error

Comment: The error is pretty descriptibe, you have syntax error in your `App.component.jsx` file. Go and check it

Comment: There is no error in App.component.jsx

Comment: How are you including it now?

Comment: Only just in webpack entry array

Comment: Can you show us your webpack config?

Comment: i have edited with webpack.config.js

Comment: actually what is babel-polyfill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I use [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill.html) in my Webpack config.

```
  entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill', 'main']
  }
```